# An app to keep score of the rankings for a chess club in Rails 7. I am having trouble with the logic ( players can't have the same rank)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, math, logic

So far I have a working App that follows these rules:

- If the higher-ranked player wins against their opponent, neither of their ranks  change
- If it’s a draw, the lower-ranked player can gain one position, unless the two players
  are adjacent.
  o So if the players are ranked 10th and 11th, and it’s a draw, no change in ranking takes place. But if the players are ranked 10th and 15th, and it’s a draw, the player with rank 15 will move up to rank 14 and the player with rank 10 will stay the same.
- If the lower-ranked player beats a higher-ranked player, the higher-ranked player will move one rank down, and the lower-level player will move up by half the difference between their original ranks.

But when I let a few players play, they end up having the same ranks which I do not want.

My current logic in my matches controller states:

```rb
class MatchesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @matches = Match.all
  end

  def new
    @match = Match.new
    @users = User.all
  end

  def create
    player_one = User.find(match_params["player_one"])
    player_two = User.find(match_params["player_two"])
    result = match_params["result"]

    @match = Match.new(player_one:player_one, player_two:player_two, result:result)
    @users = User.all

    if @match.save
      update_players_info(@match)
      redirect_to users_path, notice: "Ranks updated and match successfully recorded."
    else
      render :new, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end

  private

  def match_params
    params.require(:match).permit(:player_one, :player_two, :result)
  end

  def update_players_info(match)
    update_games_played(match.player_one)
    update_games_played(match.player_two)
    update_rank(match)
  end

  def update_games_played(player)
    User.where(:id => player.id).update_all(:games_played => player.matches.length)
  end

  def update_rank(match)
    one = match.player_one
    two = match.player_two
    result = match.result

    case result
    when 'Draw'
      if (-1..1).exclude?(one.rank - two.rank)
        one.rank > two.rank ? upgrade_rank(one) : upgrade_rank(two)
      end
    when 'Player 1 Won'
      if one.rank > two.rank
        jump_rank(one, two)
        downgrade_rank(two)
      end
    when 'Player 2 Won'
      if two.rank > one.rank
        jump_rank(two, one)
        downgrade_rank(one)
      end
    end
  end

  def downgrade_rank(player)
    User.where(:rank => player.rank + 1)[0].update(:rank => player.rank)
    player.update(:rank => player.rank + 1)
  end

  def upgrade_rank(player)
    User.where(:rank => player.rank - 1).update_all(:rank => player.rank)
    player.update(:rank => player.rank - 1)
  end

  def jump_rank(jumper, holder)
    jumper_rank = jumper.rank - ((jumper.rank - holder.rank)/2.0).round()
    until jumper_rank == jumper.rank do
      upgrade_rank(jumper)
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: One thing that might help is to create a unique index on the `rank` column in the DB. That will at least help you debug by throwing errors when you accidentally give players the same rank.

Comment: You may find this useful for managing ranks: https://github.com/brendon/acts_as_list

Comment: Sounds like ranking is almost a simplistic win counter. Perhaps winning is decided by probability that is too random. That is like throwing dice - Win probability is always the same for everyone on every throw. That means over time the results tend to spread evenly.  Another consideration, perhaps ranking should shift based on every players' "stats",  every time any one game is played.

Comment: One additional thing that would definately help you here is to move this code out of the controller and into something like a service object or ActiveJob (or multiple such objects). This lets you test it in insolation instead of having a very fat and hard to test/debug/reason about controller thats doing way to much.